# The line integral along the curve of intersection of two surfaces.

Tags: vector-analysis

> Calculate the work done by the force field $\mathbf{f}(x,y,z)=(y-z)\mathbf{i}+(z-x)\mathbf{j}+(x-y)\mathbf{k}$ along the curve of intersection of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and the plane $z=y\tan\theta$, where $0<\theta<\pi/2$. The path is traversed in a direction that appears counterclockwise when viewed from high above the $xy$-plane.

My approach:

Since the sphere and the plane intersect along an ellipse, we put $z=y\tan\theta$ in $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ to obtain

$x^2+y^2+y^2\tan^2\theta = 4\implies x^2 + y^2(1+\tan^2\theta) = 4\implies\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{4\cos^2\theta} = 1$, which is the equation of the required ellipse.

The parameterization is therefore $(x,y)=(2\cos t,2\cos\theta \sin t)$.

Thus, $\alpha(t) = 2\cos t\mathbf{i}+2\cos\theta\sin t\mathbf{j}$

$\implies \alpha'(t) = -2\sin t\mathbf{i} + 2\cos\theta\cos t\mathbf{j}$

$\therefore \mathbf{f}(\alpha(t)) = 2\cos\theta\sin t\mathbf{i}-2\cos t\mathbf{j}+(2\cos t - 2\cos\theta\sin t)\mathbf{k}$

and

$\mathbf{f}(\alpha(t))\cdot\alpha'(t) = -4\cos\theta\sin^2t-4\cos\theta\cos^2t = -4\cos\theta(\sin^2t+\cos^2t) = -4\cos\theta$

Thus $\int_a^b\mathbf{f}(\alpha(t))\cdot\alpha'(t)dt = \int_0^{2\pi}-4\cos\theta dt = -8\pi\cos\theta $

But the answer given in the book is $8\pi(\sin\theta - \cos\theta)$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are setting the $z$-component to $0$ after already having said that $z=y\tan\theta$. Your equation should read
$$\vec r(t)=\langle2\cos t,2\cos\theta\sin t,2\sin\theta\sin t\rangle$$
so
$$d\vec r(t)=\langle-2\sin t,2\cos\theta \cos t,2\sin\theta\cos t\rangle dt$$
And $$\vec f(t)=\langle2\cos\theta\sin t-2\sin\theta\sin t,2\sin\theta\sin t-2\cos t,2\cos t-2\cos\theta\sin t\rangle$$
And since the average value of $\sin^2 t$ and $\cos^2 t$ is $1/2$ and the average value of $\sin t\cos t$ is $0$ we have
$$w=\oint\vec f\cdot d\vec r=2\pi\left(-2\cos\theta+2\sin\theta+0-2\cos\theta+2\sin\theta-0\right)=8\pi(\sin\theta-\cos\theta)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the sphere is centered at the origin and the plane passes through the origin, the intersection is a circle.

One base of the plane is $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(0, 1, \tan \theta)$. Normalize it to get the orthonormal basis of the intersected plane, which is $e1=(1, 0, 0)$ and $e2=(0, \cos\theta, \sin\theta)$.

The intersected circle can be described by a polar coordinate $\alpha(t) = 2e1\cos t + 2e2\sin t$. Thus the parametric representation of the circle is $\alpha(t) = (2\cos t, 2\cos\theta \sin t, 2 \sin\theta \sin t)$

Now just use the line integral to compute the result.